# Can I host my Office Add-Ins on GitHub?

Tags: git, office365, office-addins, office-js

In order to run an Office Add-In, it is necessary to host it somewhere in Internet and then, in the manifest file, reference the HTTP endpoint where the add-in will be loaded by Office.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Created:cbbc9d22-5cf7-4e4c-8ee9-42a772aae58a-->
<OfficeApp xsi:type="ContentApp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0">
  <Id>eadaa0dd-558b-499a-9935-fb7f32fa8dac</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Me Myself</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="MyAddIn" />
  <Description DefaultValue="My Add-In" />
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <!-- HERE the address for publishing -->
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://github.com/mygituser/MyProjRepo" />
    <RequestedWidth>400</RequestedWidth>
    <RequestedHeight>400</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Can I use a Git repository/branch to host an add-in? Any side effects or recommended practices against this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using your project repository as a web server to serve the content of a web application. Even if it may work, I would not recommend this even for a pure static website because it is not made for that. Github proposes a website hosting that looks more or less what you want to achieve: a simple and seamless deployment from your repository. It is called [github pages](https://pages.github.com/).

But I would not recommend to host your application on github pages. Here my arguments

- You are using github domain not yours. If you want to move your app somewhere else your are stuck because your manifest is listed on Office Store or on your client Office. At the best you will end up with a redirect.
- You will not be able to use a custom domain name because https (for custom domain name) is not supported by github pages.
- With github pages your are very restricted when it comes to tuning some server parameters (ETag, Cache Control)

I used to host my company jekyll generated "static" and public website on github pages and I have been very disappointed, see [my blog post](http://benoitpatra.com/2016/02/12/hosting-jekyll-generated-site-on-azure-web-app-using-teamcity-automated-deployment/)

Last but not least, even if most of Microsoft samples for web add-ins show web apps with no server logic its rarely the case for real life web add-ins. I recommend you to put some logic server side even for a Single Page Application.

From your profile, you seem to be an ASP.NET enthusiast, why not hosting it on Azure web site [for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/pricing/details/app-service/). Even if in free mode you cannot have SSL on custom domain names.

Comment: I have to say, very good points and clear arguments. Will keep them into consideration!

Comment: Yeah! As always ,I let a few days pass for other answers to be posted which might be more complete. :)